# $watch not refreshing the ng-repeat list

Tags: angularjs

I have a search result list which I have to update basis on the selected page number.

```
$scope.changePage = function (currentindex, selectedPage) {  
    $scope.currentPage = selectedPage;
    $scope.selectedPageIndex = currentindex;         
    $scope.apply();        
}
```

This is where I change the $scope variable currentPage.
And this my $watch function where I change the result list based on the page number,

```
$scope.$watch('currentPage', function () {        
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage-1) * 10),
        end = begin + 10; 
    $scope.searchResultList = $scope.mainList.slice(begin, end);    // put your updation of list here 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass true flag as third argument in case $scope.$watch function could work immediately upon change of currentPage variable.
Also, you could just pass $scope variable to ensure scope variable is work properly.

```
$scope.$watch('currentPage', function (newValue, oldValue, scope) {

}, true)
```

Comment: You could check this blog if it is helpful.
https://www.sitepoint.com/mastering-watch-angularjs/

Comment: @georgeawg explanation, please

Comment: Yes, That's right. It's optional boolean.

But where did you find function as third argument in my function? It's not boolean for sure? 

I think there was confusion. Can you correct it?

Comment: In my code base, I think I pointed 2 examples out exactly.

It's for 2 function example below screenshot. Would you possibly correct it?

http://prntscr.com/pubqnr

http://prntscr.com/pubr77

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You can pass a value function as the first param and return the variable to watch.

```
$scope.$watch(
  function() { 
    return $scope.currentPage 
  }, 
  function () {        
    var begin = (($scope.currentPage-1) * 10);
    var end = begin + 10;
    $scope.searchResultList = $scope.mainList.slice(begin, end);
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use the `limitTo` filter in the `ng-repeat`:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in mainList | limitTo : 10 : (currentPage-1) * 10">
  {{item}}
</div>
```

For more information, see

- [AngularJS `limitTo` FilterAPI Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/limitTo)